# How can I force the use of a comma on the label of axis of tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing a chart with tizkpicture but my **y-Axis** looks like this:

[image]

How can i force tikz to write `0.08` instead of `8*10^-2` ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide the code of a complete small document (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) that illustrates your problem. From the picture, we can only guess at the packages and settings that you use, which is not a reliable basis for an answer. Moreover, other people with the same problem will not find your post if all it includes is the link to an image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.